# "Therefore I" or "I therefore"

Tags: word-order, sentence-patterns

I would like to understand the nuances. What is the correct way to use:
"Therefore, I …"  or "I, therefore …"

Answer (score 3):

Therefore - (adverb) "because of that", "for that reason".

Not a word I would use in ordinary conversation, but very useful in the written language.

- "I, therefore, suggest that..." x "Therefore, I suggest that..."

Semantically speaking, I can see no difference between them. The former, however, seems to emphasize the subject.

Comment: Yes. It would sound pompous if not used to stress contrast with a suggestion by a previous speaker etc.

Answer (score 0):

It's all about emphasis. When I say "Therefore, I ..." I automatically have a larger pause between 'therefore' and 'I'; whereas when I say "I, therefore ..." the pause is smaller between those two words.

"Therefore, I ..." can have more gravitas than "I, therefore ..." and can infer a level of authority, urgency or even aggression.